# I've tried to install git, maybe I've succeeded, but I can't find its app

Tags: git, macos

I've tried to install Git on my Mac (10.15.5) by tutorials on the internet.

I followed these steps:

- with terminal, I downloaded Homebrew

```sh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

- than, requested to brew install Git

```sh
% brew install git
```

both these steps have worked, I confirmed that typing on terminal:

```sh
% git --version
git version 2.27.0
```

so I know I have Git on my Mac, but I can't find its app and neither its **.dmg*. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Run `type git` and it will tell you that `git` is in `/usr/local/bin` which is where homebrew normally installs stuff.

Comment: Homebrew is an environment that provides a set of Unix tools along with package manager. The packages are distributed in their own format and usually are built on the target system.

Comment: thanks all! I'm new here, so I don't know already the especific way to ask something. 0andriy made my problem visualization much better!

Answer (score 0):

Usually brew is used as CLI installer, not every time packages installed through it appears as an application on Mac GUI env. But you can install git app via `.dmg` as well by downloading the required version from the link below:

- https://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/files/